# Show that any non-trivial homogeneous polynomial $s$ of degree $k$ can be considered as a non-trivial section of $\mathcal{O}(k)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, complex-manifolds

> Show that any non-trivial homogeneous polynomial $0 \ne s \in \mathbb{C}[z_0, \dots, z_n]$ of degree $k$ can be considered as a non-trivial section of $\mathcal{O}(k)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$.

So $\mathcal{O}(k) = \mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes k} = (\mathcal{O}(-1)^*)^{\otimes k}$ and we want to consider $s$ as a holomorphic map $$s:\mathbb{P}^n \to \mathcal{O}(-1)^* \otimes \dots \mathcal{O}(-1)^*.$$

Now since $s$ is homogeneous we also have that $$\lambda^k s(z_0, \dots, z_n) = s(\lambda z_0, \dots, \lambda z_n).$$

My issue is not understanding $\mathcal{O}(-1)^*$ properly and thus I can't see how $s$ is a map from the projective space to the tensor product. I have seen that the fiber of $$\pi: \mathcal{O}(-1)^* \to \mathbb{P}^n$$ is isomorphic to $\ell^*$ if we consider the elements of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ as pairs $(\ell, z)$ with $z \in \ell$. Can we use only the information about the fibers to show that $s$ is this kind of a map?

Comment: Typically, when working out this kind of problem, I would rely on the transition functions for the line bundle in question. Is that a technique you're familiar with?

Comment: Is there some property of the transition functions that will give some information about $s$? @QuaereVerum

Comment: Yes there is. From the transition functions, you can essentially derive what form $s$ has to take to glue to a globally defined section, starting from local trivialisations. For example, start by working out $\mathcal{O}(1)$ over $\mathbb{CP}^1$ in this way, and you'll see what I mean. Maybe you can take a more global approach, like what you are trying to do - I'd have to think about that.

Comment: Perhaps there could be a way to consider the polynomial $s$ as map $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{C}$ and restrict it to a fiber $\ell$ to get a map $\ell \to \mathbb{C}$. Essentially we are wanting for $s$ to give us a multilinear map $\ell^* \otimes \dots \otimes \ell^* \to \mathbb{C}$ if I understood this correctly. @QuaereVerum